# Executing page scripts before retrieving it's contents

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation

I've a page where i need to automate some tasks and **scrape** some data, but the page runs some JS after loading to inject some data into the DOM; that i cannot intercept (not in a good format anyway), I was hoping to find a solution that is fast and not memory consuming.

I've attempt to get the scripts myself and execute them using some headless driver (namely phantomJs) but it didn't update the page source and i'm not sure how to retrive the updated DOM from that

```
var page = GetWebPage(url);
var scripts = page.Html.QuerySelectorAll("script");

var phantomDriver = new PhantomJSDriver(PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()));
phantomDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

foreach (var script in scripts)
    phantomDriver.ExecuteScript(script.InnerText);

var at = phantomDriver.PageSource;
```

Comment: probably you'll need to use `await`...

Comment: nope, sorry, added an explicit wait until the document is ready but that didn't fix it
            `var wait = new WebDriverWait(phantomDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.00));
            wait.Until(driver1 => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)phantomDriver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 'wait'. According to [this link](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp), Selenium has both implicit and explicit waits. The example below is using an explicit wait.

To use an explicit wait, use `WebDriverWait` and `ExpectedConditions`. I'm not sure what language you're using but here's an example in python. This uses `WebDriverWait` in a try-catch block, allowing `timeout` seconds to meet the specified `ExpectedConditions`. As at June 2019, conditions are available in:

- [Java](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html);
- [Python](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html); and
- [.NET](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm)

Example code in python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56724178/executing-page-scripts-before-retrieving-its-contents'
target = (By.XPATH, "//div[@class='gravatar-wrapper-32']")
timeout = 20  # Allow max 20 seconds to find the target

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(target))
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
    browser.quit()
```

The important bit is between `try` and `except` which you would modify to use the specific 'expected condition' you're interested in.

Comment: nope, sorry, added an explicit wait until the document is ready but that didn't fix it `var wait = new WebDriverWait(phantomDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.00)); wait.Until(driver1 => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)phantomDriver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"))`

Comment: You said the page has some JS that runs AFTER loading so your code may still be running before that JS runs. Try setting the expected condition to watch an element that gets modified by the JS to detect when the code is done with its changes.